# How to format my external HDD back to as "removable storage"?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, formatting

Recently I formated my Seagate FreeAgent GoFlex external HDD in Mac OS X using GUID partition table since I wanted to install another Mac OS X onto that external HDD.

However I changed my mind after my external HDD being formatted.

Now I want to format my external HDD back to NTFS so that I can use it with my Windows 7.

However, after I connected my external HDD via USB it didn't show up in my "computer" so I used "Disk Management" to check what's wrong with it.

In the "Disk Management" I saw that there was one partition of my external HDD called "EFI partition" and I found that I could not delete this partition in the "Disk Management".

So I tried to use "diskpart" in cmd and select the external HDD and commanded "clean".

Then the EFI partition was gone and I created new volumn on that external HDD.

However, after the volumn being created my external HDD did show up in my "computer" but it is in the "Hard Disk Drive" not in the "Devices with Removable Storage" as it used to be.

I'm wondering if I can do anything to it to make it recognized as a "Devices with Removable Storage"?

Comment: If Windows 7 thought your external hard drive was removable storage, it was wrong. Likely it was just misinterpreting the EFI or HFS+ partitions.

Comment: That EFI partition is a special partition used for booting from the drive.  If you don't plan to boot from it anymore, it's OK to delete, but there's no harm leaving it there.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to be recognized as a removable storage device I believe you should format it as FAT32.